# How do I mount a disk to provide needed space on top level directory?

Tags: mount, fstab, disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a disk with about 80GB of storage.  Recently, I started getting errors reporting that I did not have enough storage space.  I have other drives with several Terra-bytes free.  The mount command seems clear enough in some ways.  As I add software, and the log files grow, I'm not sure how to mount drives permanently ( using /etc/fstab file) to meet the need for more space.  In particular, I need more space for the /var partition, as well as /bin, /sbin, and perhaps /etc directories.  Can I or should I, mount /dev/sdb1 to '/'?
      I had tried mounting a smaller disk to /home/bruce and the system said the folder was busy.  I haven't tried mounting to '/' as I don't know if that will address the issue.  Oh, they are all internal disks so they will likely be automatically mounted, or that is what I am observing when I boot my system.
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Comment: I am a bit confused with the first answer, where I could use some clarification.  So, I clone my current 80GB partition, which I guess gives me a iso or similar image.  I have a 1.8TB partition from a previous installation.    I could format that.  I could expand the 80GB image onto the 1.8TB partition but will I still need to install Ubuntu into that partition - or can I even do that?  It seems that I need to install the Grub boot loader such that it doesn't load the Ubuntu on my small disk and instead load it from the large disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution for you, would be to clone the 80GB hard drive to one of your other drives with with "several Terra-bytes free".

Ubuntu by default will just install everything into one big / partition. If your system is set up this way, you can use something like clonezila or acronis to clone the drive and expand the / partition across the new drive. This way /var, /bin, /sbin, and /etc will all have more space.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to add more storage to the / directory without reinstalling the OS, unless your / partition is a logical volume.

Also remember, when you are going through the desktop Ubuntu installation, if you select the "something else" radio button on the partitioning page you can choose which drives are going to be mounted to which locations.

Mounting hard drives in fstab is a good idea for when you are permanently mounting drives to locations that are not critical to the OS system. If you think you will want to add more memory to the system later on, I strongly suggest that you set your system up with an LVM because this will make the process much easier for you in the future.

Comment: I did select LVM during installation.  So, I guess I need to figure out how that can be used to address my issue.  You said, "Unfortunately there is no easy way to add more storage to the / directory without reinstalling the OS, unless your / partition is a logical volume."  Do you mean, if LVM is setup?

Comment: A logical volume is part of LVM. The link below is a really good video that explains what LVM is and it shows you how to expand an existing logical volume. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BysRGDgqtwY  You can use fdisk -l to find out which device is the large hard drive. Then, just follow the steps in the video.

Comment: So don't reinstall your OS because if you selected LVM during the installation, then your / partition should be a logical volume.